# having issue when try to getting selected value in optionmenu in tkinter(python3)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to get value which is selected from the list in drop-down menu but having this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3436, in __call__
    self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
TypeError: changeInLymph() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

My code is:

```
# dropDown options
def changeInLymph():
    data = "you selected the option " + var10.get()
    label10.config(text=data)

var10 = StringVar()
choices = ['bean', 'oval', 'round']
 # set the default option

popupMenu = OptionMenu(f1, var10, *choices ).grid(row = 20, column =5)

Label(f1, text="Choose a dish").grid(row = 19, column = 5)

label10 = Label(f1).grid(row=21,column=1)

where i am doing wrong please help anybody.
```

Comment: how did you call the function `changeInLymph`?  seems like you need to assign an argument to that function.

Comment: error is not in this part of code , where are you calling function changeInLymph()?

Comment: popupMenu = OptionMenu(f1, var10, *choices,command=  changeInLymph).grid(row = 18, column =6)
I used now but still not resolved error is File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3436, in __call__
    self.__callback(self.__value, *args)
TypeError: changeInLymph() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: what is "0 positional arguments but 1 was given" can help in that